# ExecuteScalar multiple transactions

Tags: c#, executescalar

I am trying to execute ExecuteScalar() with 2 instruction with ODBC connection to mysql in a query. My query is :

```
string query = @"SET @MY_ID := (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id) + 1, 1) FROM sc);" + Environment.NewLine + "INSERT INTO sc (id, name) values (@MY_ID, 'TESTE');"
```

I am getting:

`{System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]
[mysqld-5.0.83-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'INSERT INTO`

Comment: Does your provider allow multiple statements in one query (ExecuteScalar)? Also, it's recommended to use an `auto increment` for the identifier field, and not to do it yourself.

Comment: Why `ExecuteScalar`? Shouldn't it be `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: 1- I am using ExecuteScalar becouse i need the id created. The query will be: "string query = @"SET @MY_ID := (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id) + 1, 1) FROM sc);" + Environment.NewLine + "INSERT INTO sc (id, name) values (@MY_ID, 'TESTE');" + Environment.NewLine + "SELECT @MY_ID;"

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `SET` to initialize a variable from a result set, you would need to actually execute the query

```
 SELECT @MY_ID := ...
```

Comment: Also does not work looks like he cant run the second statement. 
{System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]
[mysqld-5.0.83-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
 to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO

Comment: Obviously *something* in your query is not supported syntax, just build up your statement bit by bit until you hit the query that it doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string query = "Declare @MY_ID int;Select @MY_ID  = IFNULL(MAX(id) + 1, 1) from sc;INSERT INTO sc (id, name) values (@MY_ID, 'TESTE');"
OleDBCommand command=new OleDbCommand(query,connectionObj);
int status;

status=command.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(status>0)
{
//success
}
```

Comment: can you explain string query = "Update MyTable SET "+MY_ID+" if what i need is just to generate new id, insert into a table and return the created id

Comment: Does not work
{System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver]
[mysqld-5.0.83-community-nt]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Declare